# Integral of Bessel function $K_0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I find myself dealing with the following integral $$
\int_{-1} ^1 dt \,e^{it} K_0(b t), 
$$
and I was thinking if this can be somehow expressed in terms of something nice, like other Bessel functions for instance. $b $ is a constant and $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start with $K_0(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xu)}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}} du$ and see where that leads you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure (at all) that there is a solution to this problem and I am afraid that only numerical integration could be the only way to go.

What I would do is to generate tables for a series of values of $b$ and use any method of interpolation (independently for the real and imaginary parts of the result); the functions are really smooth.

I give below a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b & \text{real part} & \text{imaginary part} \\
 0.25 & +2.98678 & -2.65532 \\
 0.50 & +1.83156 & -2.69092 \\
 0.75 & +1.14941 & -2.75129 \\
 1.00 & +0.64764 & -2.83803 \\
 1.25 & +0.23109 & -2.95345 \\
 1.50 & -0.14555 & -3.10066 \\
 1.75 & -0.50939 & -3.28370 \\
 2.00 & -0.87976 & -3.50766 \\
 2.25 & -1.27265 & -3.77889 \\
 2.50 & -1.70300 & -4.10521 \\
 2.75 & -2.18611 & -4.49626 \\
 3.00 & -2.73868 & -4.96380 \\
 3.25 & -3.37976 & -5.52223 \\
 3.50 & -4.13165 & -6.18909 \\
 3.75 & -5.02096 & -6.98583 \\
 4.00 & -6.07974 & -7.93861 \\
 4.25 & -7.34693 & -9.07937 \\
 4.50 & -8.87001 & -10.4472 \\
 4.75 & -10.7072 & -12.0898 \\
 5.00 & -12.9298 & -14.0658
\end{array}
\right)$$